# grep output to file does not work - ping www.google.com |grep -v "time=1." >>ping.log

Tags: grep, redirection

```
ping  www.google.com |grep  -v "time=1." >>ping.log
```

Nothing is appended to the logfile, without the redirection the command works fine. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Output is buffered. Try to unbuffer it using `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 command`. It might be enough to use `stdbuf -o0`.

Comment: What is the OS? Different solutions may be available in different systems and for different implementations of `grep`.

Comment: Am running Linux 4.1.27 aarch64 on an Asus router , neither stdbuf   or --line-buffered are supported . Will have to try and write a script to perform the same.  Thanks for the feedback !

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
ping  www.google.com | grep -v --line-buffered "time=1." >> ping.log
```

`--line-buffered` will force buffering to be flushed with each line so that you can output them to the file. See [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Other-Options.html).

Your way works as well, but you need to wait some time until the buffer is full, then it gets output to the file.

Comment: I suggest to replace `1.` with `1\.` because it's a regex.